# How to calculate growth rate using Big O?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

I am just starting to learn about Big O notation and had a question about how to calculate the growth rate of an algorithm. Suppose I had an algorithm with O(√n log n) time complexity, and for n = 10 my algorithm takes 2 seconds. If I want to know how long it would take with n = 100, do I set up a ratio where 2/x = (√10 log 10)/(√100 log 100) and then solve for x? Or can I just say that my input is 10 times larger, so it will take 2*(√10 log 10) seconds?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The first method is right.  Big O doesn't care about constant multiples so you can determine the constant by solving for it with algebra.

```
c*(√10*log(10)) = 2
c = 2/(√10*log(10))
√100*log(100) * 2/(√10*log(10)) = x
```

However, keep in mind that big O also doesn't care about 'smaller' terms and so those constant overheads and other smaller-scaling factors will only make this calculation asymptotically accurate.  For example, an algorithm governed by the following equation:

(√n log n + 1/n) = t

is still O(√n log n) and this will make your calculations less accurate for small values of n.

Comment: remark that big O is an upper bound, so the growth rate would also be an upper bound.  this means that the number that you get tells you that the program will be no slower than, but it can be a lot faster than.  if an algorithm is O(1), it is O(n).  if it is O(n^p) it is O(n^q) for q>p.  if it is O(n^p) it is O(u^n) for u > 1.  etc.

Comment: Yes, you can only solve for the constant if the bound is tight. And then you can still only estimate the constant.